# It's not possible load Highstock from the CDN as an AMD module

Tags: highcharts, requirejs

##### Expected behaviour

Hello I'd like to import Highstock lib using RequireJs AMD Module, as recommended in readme.md in github Highcharts/Highstock: [GitHub Highcharts](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts)

Example to import Highchart in documentation:

```js
require.config({
  packages: [
    {
      name: "highcharts",
      main: "highcharts",
    },
  ],
  paths: {
    // Change this to your server if you do not wish to use our CDN.
    highcharts: "https://code.highcharts.com",
  },
});
```

Demos:
[Import AMD Highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/amd/simple/) 
[Import AMD multiple version Highchart](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/amd/version-mix/)

##### Actual behaviour

If I try use highstock.js As the example below, it won´t works:

```js
/**
 * Tell RequireJS how and where to search for the highcharts package
 */
require.config({
  packages: [
    {
      name: "highcharts",
      main: "highcharts",
    },
  ],
  paths: {
    highcharts: `${libPath}/highstock/9.1.2`,
  },
});
define(["highcharts", "highcharts/modules/exporting", "highcharts/highcharts-more"], function (Highcharts) {
  "use strict";
     //highstock code here... 
});
```

To make this work it's needed change the `highstock.js` file name to `highcharts.js` due to the name defined in lib highstock:
**"highcharts/highcharts"**

```js
//Lib Highstock content
define("highcharts/highcharts", function () {
  return factory(root);
});
```

As I can´t change the name:

```js
 {
   name: "highcharts",
   main: "highcharts",
 }
//to
 {
   name: "highstock",
   main: "highstock",
 }
```

The requireJs never will find the `highstock.js` file, to do so, I have to change the file name to `highcharts.js`.

I appreciate any support.

Comment: Hi @Fábio, There is probably some restriction due to package name. You can load stock as a highcharts module: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n173g05q/ or load highstock as different package name: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nkabj2sz/

Comment: In general, Highstock is Highcharts with additional features. These features can also be added to Highcharts by the `stock` module. Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/understanding-highcharts-stock

Comment: Thaks @ppotaczek, I was mistake a config in requireJs (require.config), you help me a lot

Comment: Probably you can use `map` configuration option to map highstock to highcharts, more here https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map

Answer (score 0):

I was calling by Highstock in wrong way:

```js
/**
 * Tell RequireJS how and where to search for the highcharts package
 */
require.config({
  packages: [
    {
      name: "highcharts",
      main: "highcharts",
    },
  ],
```

The correct way to call by highstock lib is:

```js
    packages: [
    {
      name: "highcharts",
      main: "highstock",
    },
```